# why does [[:xdigit:]] highlight letter e in grep results?

Tags: regex, grep, hex, character-class

Why does below command highlight **e** as well with digits?

```
grep '[[:xdigit:]]' search.txt
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intended, as it searches for **hexadecimal digits**.

The [man-page](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html) states:

[image]